# Ruby on Rails - Collection_select, option class

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collection-select, chained-select

is it possible to pass a model-attribute of the collection to the select-options class?

```html
<%= f.collection_select :bank_connection_id, BankConnection.all, :id, :bank_name, {:class => ? } %>
```

The Questmark shows where i wanted to use a attribute of the BankConnection. The attribute is named customer_id.

Background of this: I want to use the chained plugin for rails and therefore i must set the class to the specific customer-id.

Thanks for your help.

Tobias

Comment: If the current instance the `form` is for can access `customer_id` then you should be able to do `{ class: f.object.customer_id }`, where `f.object` is the reference to the current instance the form is built for.

Comment: Sorry this did not help. I have switched to the select funktion according to the tutorial: http://homeonrails.blogspot.de/2012/01/rails-31-linked-dropdown-cascading.html